# Reuse Magento collection

Tags: collection, optimization

Can we use a fetched Magento collection more than once?

If Yes, then how is it implemented?

#### For Example:

I have an action in a controller in which I fetched all the products with its required attribute. Now I have to perform filters and sorting to that collection via AJAX.

```
 public function getProductCollection(){

 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('a1')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('a3')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('a4')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('...');

        return $collection;

}
```

Now I have another action

```
public function sortcollection(){
/*
    Here I want to apply filter and sorting to the collection fetched in
    above action. It this is not possible than I am open to apply filters
    and sorting in previous action as well but without fetching collection
    again. 
*/
}
```

Comment: Are both functions in the same class ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is entirely possible. If collection is not large enough to cause memory issues, you can put it in `Mage::registry()`, it will be accessible throughout the life-cycle of that request afterwards.

Also, if both functions are in same class, you can put that collection in a class property, this way, your collection will be available only in that class but to all the methods.

In case, you are trying to retain data between multiple requests, I'd suggest using sessions. As mentioned in the comments, sessions are not an option here. So, you can try that with the frontend only. Collection will not be re-used, but I don't think that is going to be any issue anymore, as collection will not be loaded twice in one request cycle.

To achieve that, you can try mimicking what Magento does with category pages for pagination and sorting. Everytime user selects any option in frontend, you will need to retain that data itself in template, either in JS objects or as properties of some special HTML elements.

Providing a code sample would be tough unless you show what methods you are using in frontend and how they are being handled in backend, as there can be 100 possible ways to get this and my sample could be completely different than what you have now. Some changes in your existing code will be little headache than having a total new approach for some minor issue.

Also, looking at the code you supplied, if it's just about working with the multiple actions in same controller with pre-defined parameters(I highly doubt that's the case though!), wrap your logic inside a method that is not an action, and call that method in both of your actions. You'll get identical collection in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.. 

But I have tried it with registry. In First action after fetching collection data I used that registry to display all the results via template.

Now from template I am sending an AJAX request to second action and I am unable to use that registry in my second action.

Comment: Registry is maintained only for a single request cycle, if you want to retain the data for your second request, I'd suggest using sessions instead. Only session data can be maintained for multiple requests.

Comment: My collection consists of 2000 products and it is not a best way to use session as it will use large amount of memory.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to retain the data in your template files, based upon which you fired first request, and send them again in second request so that same filters will be applied second time. Only this way, you can achieve what you desire.

Comment: Could you please send me any example snippet for that that would be more helpful as I am new to magento ?

Answer (score 0):

you can magento session for that

```
public function getProductCollection(){

 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('a1')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('a3')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('a4')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('...');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCustomCollection($collection);
        return $collection;

}
```

you retrieve in  function

```
public function sortcollection(){
$collection=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getsCustomCollection();
/*
    Here I want to apply filter and sorting to the collection fetched in
    above action. It this is not possible than I am open to apply filters
    and sorting in previous action as well but without fetching collection
    again. 
*/
}
```

Comment: My collection consists of 2000 products and it is not a best way to use session as it will use large amount of memory.

Comment: if you don't want to load all the collection then simple store there ids in session  $collection->getAllIds();

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCustomCollection( $collection->getAllIds());   this will save only the product ids

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Could you please clarify that the above functionality can help in perform the following operations:
1. Sorting of products on the basis of attributes.
2. Filter on collection on attribute basis.
3. Collection related queries.

Comment: can you explain what you want in detail?

Comment: For ex:-  I have 200 products in database which has 50 attributes each. When page loads it will display all the products with their attributes values which is done by via collection and show them in tabular format. Now user can apply various filters on the basis of attributes values lets say they want product of price between $100-$200 then I don't want to fire a query on DB instead of that is there any way by which I can sort it within the collection which i have fetched earlier

Comment: are you trying to create the ajax layered navigation?

Comment: No, I am just displaying all the products in tabular format and apply filters and sorting on the basis of product attributes

Comment: Tried the code and check the time

Comment: Can you explain more about your last comment ?

Comment: Kindly try the solution and check how much time it's taking. Magento uses the session for collection too